# Wave functions as being square-integrable vs. normalizable

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction

I am a physics undergraduate. I am working in the world of textbook (non-relativistic) Quantum Mechanics. Say we have a wave function $\Psi(x,t)$. Must $\Psi(x,t)$ be square-integrable or normalizable?

To my understanding, normalizable implies square-integrable. However, square-integrable does not imply normalizable. For example, $f(x,t) = 0$ is square-integrable, but it is not normalizable.

This leads me to think that a wave function $\Psi(x,t)$ must be *normalizable*, a stricter requirement than just square-integrable. In particular, $f(x,t) = 0$ is not a wave function and thus cannot represent a physical state.

And, as an application of this tentative result, could one explain why particle annihilation is not built into (non-relativistic) textbook Quantum Mechanics by appealing to the fact that the evolution of a wave function $\Psi(x,t)$ into the wavefunction $f(x,t) = 0$ (after some time has elapsed) is not possible since $0$ itself is not a wave function?

Comment: Related: [Hilbert space vs. Projective Hilbert space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/156907/168783), [Quantum states as rays as opposed to vectors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76939/168783)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a really nice remark. States are actually not quite vectors on the Hilbert space, but rather rays of vectors. Hence, indeed, they should be normalizable rather than square-integrable. In practice, this means that the allowed wavefunctions are the non-vanishing square-integrable functions (notice all of these are indeed normalizable, where I take "function" to mean actually an equivalence class of functions that are equal [almost everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere)).

As for the evolution, notice that if QM were to describe particle annihilation, it should also be able to describe particle creation because it is time-reversible. However, you can't give a wavefunction a interpretation of two particles at once. It only tells you how to find a single particle.

From a more mathematical point of view, saying that $\psi = 0$  at any time (e.g., after annihilation) determines the whole evolution of the state. Notice that evolving the Schrödinger equation to any time with $\psi(0,x) = 0$ can only lead to $\psi(t,x) = 0$. Hence, wanting to describe the state of the system with a single wavefunction will also prevent one from getting $\psi(t_0,x) = 0$ at any particular time $t_0$, unless the wavefunction vanishes at all times.

To actually describe particle creation and annihilation, one must use different formalisms, such as second-quantization and quantum field theory. While this keeps the main ideas of QM (states are vectors on a Hilbert space, observables are operators, etc), you no longer deal with wavefunctions, and the states now live in a more complicated Hilbert space known as [Fock space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space). This space does have states corresponding to different particle numbers and it should be mentioned that even now that particle annihilation is possible, the vacuum state (no particles) is not $\psi = 0$, but rather a non-vanishing vector corresponding to zero particles.

Comment: I disagree (somehow) with this answer. First of all, what does the fact that states are rays instead of vectors has to do with the question *at all*? Second, you still have a many-body wave function, even in second quantization. You can even work in a $N$-particle state without ever using the idea of a Fock space (in first quantization). Finally, what exactly do you mean in your discussion with the evolving wave function? Do you mean $\psi(t,x)$ vanishes for all $t$ and $x$ or only a particular $x$? What I mean is this: Take e.g. the particle in the box, the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian..

Comment: ...vanish for some specific $x$; this holds for all times. But I could misunderstood your argument there: If you meant to say that your initial condition in the Schrödinger equation is $\psi=0$, the zero vector, then yes, by unitarity of the time-evolution operator, the solution of this initial value problem is the (constant) zero vector.

Comment: @TobiasFünke The zero vector is a vector, but not a ray (at least in my understanding of a ray). I've never seen a many-particle wavefunction, maybe that's a concept from outside my area (I'm used to field theory). As for my discussion of the evolving wavefunction, I meant for all $t$ and $x$. As you said, if the initial condition is the zero vector, unitarity implies it will evolve only to (or from) the zero vector, although I wrote it in a more PDE-like way (seemed more appropriate imo for starters in QM)

Comment: Notice that saying that states are rays rather than vectors is then just a way of rephrasing that they are normalizable rather than square-integrable. In both cases, the difference in the sets is essentially just the zero vector (up to, well, normalization or a constant phase).

Comment: Ah, I see so you (and probably the most sources), define rays in a way that excludes the zero vector (i.e. a ray is an equivalence class between non-zero vectors)? Regarding the other thing: There are many-body wave functions.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Precisely.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that in order to represent a valid physical state, a wavefunction $\psi(x)$ must be normalizable and not just square-integrable. In practice, people tend to (sloppily) use those two terms interchangeably, because the only functions that are square-integrable but not normalizable are those that are zero almost everywhere - and since the Hilbert space of physical states identifies together functions that are equal almost everywhere, all of these functions correspond to a single vector (not state!) $|0\rangle$ in the Hilbert space. (Here the notation $|0\rangle$ represents the additive identity vector in the Hilbert space, *not* the ground state of any Hamiltonian.)

So the space of square-integrable functions does indeed include unphysical wavefunctions, but they all only correspond to a single unphysical vector in the Hilbert space. So it's *almost* correct to say that all (really should be "almost all") square-integrable wavefunctions represent a valid physical state.